# Recyclerview custom button is invalid on fragment click?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

My recyclerview item is divided into upper and lower parts. The part below the item is expanded and collapsed in the adapter. But I need to click the button below the item in the fragment to work, but I try to do a custom click, but he has no toast response ??

I'll use //... to reduce unneeded code.

adapter

```
class TalkAdapter(private val talkData: ArrayList<TalkData>):RecyclerView.Adapter<TalkAdapter.TalkViewHolder>(),View.OnClickListener {

    private var mOnItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener? = null
    
    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener?) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener
    }
    
    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(view: View?, position: Int)
        fun onItemLongClick(v: View?)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TalkViewHolder {
        val view=TalkViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.talk_recyclerview_use,parent,false))
        return view
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TalkViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.buttonJoin.tag=position
        //...
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return talkData.size
    }

    class TalkViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        //...
        val buttonJoin=itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonJoinuse)

    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        val position = view?.getTag() as Int
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
            when (view.getId()) {
                R.id.recyclerViewTalk -> mOnItemClickListener!!.onItemClick(view,position)
                else -> mOnItemClickListener!!.onItemClick(view,  position)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

recyclerview layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.hope1.DetailViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        //... >

        //...

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTalk"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            //... />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    //...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/talk_recyclerview_use">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutUp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        //... >

        //...
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutDown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        //...>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            //...>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:text="參加"
                //... />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:text="不參加"
                //... />
        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonJoinuse"
            android:text="確定"
            //... />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var talkAdapter: TalkAdapter
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding= FragmentDetailBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.lifecycleOwner=this
        val viewModelFactory=DetailViewModelFactory(sportData,application)
        binding.viewModel= ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory).get(DetailViewModel::class.java)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        talkAdapter=TalkAdapter(talkList)
        binding.recyclerViewTalk.adapter=talkAdapter

        talkAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : TalkAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(view: View?, position: Int) {
                when(view?.id){
                    R.id.buttonJoinuse->{
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you are missing any information.Please help everyone. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use "setOnClickListener" instead of "OnItemClickListener"

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But where should I write it?

Comment: change "OnItemClickListener" to "setOnClickListener" in your code